# Custom background image on NSTableViewCell

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have a view based tableview with a custom cell with a bunch of labels and an image on it. I want to add a background image to each cell. First I tried adding an imageview to the cell but that covers up the selection highlight. I then tried to set the background of the tableview but the image moves when resizing the view. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you want the image to display in the cell? For example is will it fill the bounds, tile, stretch, or will the table view fix to the image size? Probably the easiest way is subclass NSTableRowView and set the backgroundColor property will an image loaded into NSColor. But this might not be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to boyfarrell I was able to figure it out. I did as he suggested and subclassed NSTableRowView and added the background in `drawBackgroundInRect:` like this:

```
- (void)drawBackgroundInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{    
    NSImage *backgroundImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"plaincellbg.png"];
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:self.bounds fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
}
```

The image fills the cell and stretches when the window is resized.